# dcasting a dataframe using reshape2::dcast

Tags: r, reshape2

I am trying to reshape a dataframe using `dcast` function of `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)
dat = data.frame(aa = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'))
dcast(dat, aa~aa)
```

This generates below output

```
  aa A B C
1  A 1 0 0
2  B 0 2 0
3  C 0 0 2
```

However I wanted to keep the number of rows same as my original dataframe as below

[image]

Is there any direct function to get my desired shape?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tidyverse or base R you can do:

```r
dat = data.frame(aa = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'))
                  
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  mutate(id = seq_along(aa), val = 1) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = aa, values_from = val, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     0
#> 2     0     1     0
#> 3     0     0     1
#> 4     0     0     1
#> 5     0     1     0

as.data.frame(sapply(unique(dat$aa), \(x) as.numeric(x == dat$aa)))
#>   A B C
#> 1 1 0 0
#> 2 0 1 0
#> 3 0 0 1
#> 4 0 0 1
#> 5 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add first an id column with `row_number` and `spread` the aa column to your desired output but with the columnames as values. To `replace` these you can replace `everything` `across` the columns if it is not 0 with 1 like this:

```r
dat = data.frame(aa = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(aa, aa, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . != 0, 1)))
#>   A B C
#> 1 1 0 0
#> 2 0 1 0
#> 3 0 0 1
#> 4 0 0 1
#> 5 0 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `fastDummies`

```
library(fastDummies)
out <- dummy_cols(dat, "aa", remove_selected_columns = TRUE) 
 names(out) <- sub(".*_", "", names(out))
```

-output

```
> out
  A B C
1 1 0 0
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
4 0 0 1
5 0 1 0
```

---

Or with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(dat), seq_along(aa) ~ aa, value.var = 'aa', length)[,-1]
   A B C
1: 1 0 0
2: 0 1 0
3: 0 0 1
4: 0 0 1
5: 0 1 0
```